# How were the “seven good men of the city” appointed?

Tags: halacha, history, politics-government, voting, tractate-megillah

How were the [“seven good men of the city” שבעה טובי העיר](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=7&perek=11&halocha=17&hilite=) appointed? Was there an election and if so who could be candidates?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18866